# remove the links from the text using python

Tags: python

I need to remove link from the a number of text lines. A sample is given below:
**b'585947808772960257|wed apr 08 23:30:18 +0000 2015|gp workload harming care - bma poll http://bbc.in/1chtbrv\r\n'**
I tried the python code
text = re.sub(r'^http://.*[\r\n]*', '', text)
but it gives an error
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Can I remove the binary text from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the binary string first using .decode() method:

```
binary_string = b'585947808772960257|wed apr 08 23:30:18 +0000 2015|gp workload harming care - bma poll http://bbc.in/1chtbrv\r\n'
# decode the binary string
string = binary_string.decode("utf-8")
# find the url pattern
repstring = re.search('.*(http:\/\/.*)\r\n', string).group(1)
# replace the url pattern
text = re.sub(repstring, '', binary_string.decode("utf-8") )
```

If you need to have the result in binary format again, you need to encode again:

```
text_binary = str.encode(text)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but is there a way to separate b'585947808772960257| from the string. It is not useful for analysis

Comment: what do you mean with separate?

Answer (score 0):

The `b` prefix means it is a `bytes` object, you need to know the `encoding` in order to decode it and turn it into a `string` object.

```
a = b'585947808772960257|wed apr 08 23:30:18 +0000 2015|gp workload harming care - bma poll http://bbc.in/1chtbrv\r\n'
print(type(a))
>>> <class 'bytes'>
```

If you run decode without parameter, it will use `utf-8`:

```py
decoded_a = a.decode()
print(decoded_a)
>>> 585947808772960257|wed apr 08 23:30:18 +0000 2015|gp workload harming care - bma poll http://bbc.in/1chtbrv  

print(type(decoded_a))
>>> <class 'str'>
```